# serviceInfo.getAttributes is empty in onServiceResolved in Android 5.1 to 6.0 (Network Service Discovery)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nsd

I am trying to read TXT records in my app .ATTRIBUTES TEST is {}.

```
public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

    Log.e("ATTRIBUTES TEST",serviceInfo.getAttributes()+"");            
}
```